# Chrome dev tools not showing comments

Tags: css, google-chrome

Chrome CSS editor in dev tools not showing comments.

## See original file

[image]

## And this is how chrome showing it *Comment removed*

[image]

I think its just me who noticed this as i have not found any question for this on internet.

It was very useful & easy before that we just needed copy all new css in chrome editor at once and paste it into file. But now we need to see what to we added/edited/removed before adding it to file.

Please anyone how to make chrome to show comments in editor?

Comment: Chrome by default will parse css contents so that comments are removed. Don't use Chrome editor.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy It was all ok in earlier versions of chrome. Cant stop using chrome :(

Comment: Another method: directly open the link of the css file. I do think the comments here won't be removed.

Comment: What@SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy What about modified CSS in editor?

Comment: Sadly commemnt will be removed in this case

Comment: I cannot seem to duplicate your issue. Tested various versions of Chrome, up to v54, but they all show the comment in the CSS, both in the inspector and in the editor.

Comment: So it's just me? Even i reset my chrome!